# Source Not Found main.xml Beginning Android 4 Application Development by Wei-Meng Lee, Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am beginning android 4 application development and in fact going through a book that is teaching me android. I am an chapter 4 and seem to have run into a problem that's been driving me insane. I am making a simple android app that displays presidents in a checkbox list and when you click a button, it will displayed what you have picked. It does not give me a chance though because it gives me the error "Source Not Found" right when I open the app on the emulator. Here is my code for the app.

```
package net.learn2develop.Basicviews5;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BasicViews5Activity extends ListActivity {

    String[] presidents;

/** called when there activity is first created */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lstView = getListView();
    // lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    //lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    presidents = 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents_array);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, presidents));
}

public void onListItemClick(
        ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "You have selceted " + presidents[position],
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    ListView lstView = getListView();

    String itemsSelected = "Selcted items: \n";
    for (int i=0; i<lstView.getCount(); i++) {
        if (lstView.isItemChecked(i)) {
            itemsSelected += lstView.getItemAtPosition(i) + "\n";
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, itemsSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basic_views5, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my code for the main.xml file I invoke. (or try to anyways.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".BasicViews5Activity" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show selceted items"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my strings.xml file that invokes the presidents strings to put in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="app_name">BasicViews5</string>
<string-array name="presidents_array">
    <item>Dwight D. Eisenhower</item>
    <item>John F. Kennedy</item>
    <item>Lyndon B. Johnson</item>
    <item>Richard Nixon</item>
    <item>Gerald Ford</item>
    <item>Jimmy Carter</item>
    <item>Ronald Reagen</item>
    <item>George H. W. Bush</item>
    <item>Bill Clinton</item>
    <item>George W. Bush</item>
    <item>Barack Obama</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

I really dont know whats going on here. I did some investigating and I narrowed the problem it seems to one line of code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I take it out, its fine, But I don't have the button that displays what you have selected. I put it in and it goes berserk and says source not found and the emulator is blank. I know that my post is long but thank you so much for taking the time to read it! Any help you can give me will be much appreciated!

Comment: do you have a `main.xml` in your `res/layout` folder?

Comment: Yes. This the the main.xml I am refering to

Comment: What if you change this line ` ListView lstView = getListView();` to ` ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` Then change your `TextVivew` in xml to `ListView`?

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Please re post as answer and I will check it!

Comment: Glad I could help. Give me a few and I will post an answer

Comment: I have posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to answer:

You are calling `getListView()` but giving an id to `TextView` of `android:id="@+id/android:list"` which the app is looking for. You only call `getListVivew()` if you haven't declared one in your xml, then it will by default create the `ListView`.

Change this line

`ListView lstView = getListView();`

to

```
ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Then change your `TextView` in xml to `ListView`

Now  it is looking for a `ListView` with the proper `id`. This also allows you to format your `ListView` further by using `styles` and `themes` if you wish to change the appearance

Answer (score 0):

On page 192 (Chapter 4) in the book it has the following code snippet in the `onCreate` method:

```
//---no need to call this---
//setContenetView(R.layout.main);
```

That's because you are using `ListActivity` which is going to make the content view a `ListView`. If you wanted to have a custom layout with other views defined: make your class extend only `Activity`. Then in your main.xml file you can put something like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Now, in you `onCreate` method you can call: `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and below that reference the listview:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
```